# Allow numbers only after some alphabet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make sure that a certain  field only takes numbers as after some default alphabetic characters Like **XXX-XX-1234**. Here XXX-XX-  are default characters which shouldn't be removed. After these alphabets I want the user to be unable to type in any characters other than numbers.

Is there a neat way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery plugin for preventing entering any input not matching a regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425497/jquery-plugin-for-preventing-entering-any-input-not-matching-a-regexp)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp ;)

Comment: There might be, but this is Stackoverflow, so: what have you tried, in where in the code that you wrote did you get stuck?

Comment: I know about  disabling only numeric numbers or only alphabetic characters. but don't know such type of validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with input regex pattern too

```
<input type="text" name="my_name"
  pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}" title="my title">
```

in your case   (removing the number)

```
 <input type="text" name="my_name" value="ABC-DE" 
  pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}-[A-Za-z]{2}-" title="my title">
```

Comment: Please note this is supported from IE11 and partly supported by safari and iOS

Comment: Is there any javascript involved here?

Comment: this is pure HTML5 no javascript

Comment: It is writing everything there

Comment: Or it works on running time after some php get or post method gets the value

Comment: I want to remove numbers after `XXX-XX-` but it was not removing anything.

Comment: No php involved is pure html5 ..(is a proper method o the input tag)  .. i have update the answer for remove the number

Comment: I tried like `<input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="Enter numbers"   value="XXX-XX-"
                                   pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}" title="my title">`. Here I have added value: `XXX-XX-` there. Which is the default value every time. After that I want the user to be unable to type any alphabetic value

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aeoril/ubhdsp9s/)

I wish I could have made this a comment on @scaisEdge 's answer because I just built off of it to add a little more helpful stuff but it is just too much to fit in a comment:

HTML:

```html
<form>
  <button>submit</button>
  <input type="text" name="name1" value="ABC-DE-" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}-[A-Za-z]{2}-\d{4}$" title="LLL-LL-DDDD - L is any letter, D is any digit" />
  <input type="text" name="name2" value="XXX-XX-" pattern="XXX-XX-\d{4}$" title="XXX-XX-DDDD - D is any digit, rest as is" />
</form>
```

I used his answer as a base, then did the following to illustrate more:

- I added "\d{4}$" to the end of the regex pattern to force 4 numbers then nothing else
- I added a new text input that showed how to force explicitly specific characters for the alphebetic/dash portion
- I added titles with helpful pattern hints because those are shown in the popup when the pattern is rejected
- I put it all in a form with a submit button to show how it all works together

**What not to do**

I spent a lot of time "rolling my own" code to make a version of a text input that specifically limited all actions on it up front (on input change, keydown, keyup, mouse click) to only allow putting in the last 4 digits and nothing else.  It became a game of "chase the corner cases" and I quickly became convinced that using a plugin or library that is thoroughly vetted by the developer community is the way to go for such an endeavor, or using the pattern attribute as discussed above.

Not only was it "vertically oriented" toward this specific pattern, I failed even after much time to iron out all the corner cases and it remained broken.

I even gave an explanation of these difficulties and put up the code and my FIDDLE in this answer, but realized that putting up broken code is just not a good idea on StackOverflow so I made the appropriate edits just now to redo this explanation and get rid of the FIDDLE and code for the alternate route I tried.